# What is the difference between Runtime.exit(0) and System.exit(0) in Java?

Tags: java, runtime, system

What is the difference between

> Runtime.exit(0) and System.exit(0)

Similarly what is the difference between

> Runtime.gc() and System.gc()

When to use which?

Comment: `System.exit(n)` internally call `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(n)` and same is for `gc()`.

Answer (score 2):

The System.Xxxx is shorter. Runtime.Xxxx() cannot be used directly.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between
>
> ```
> Runtime.exit(0) and System.exit(0)
> ```

None.

> Similarly what is the difference between
>
> ```
> Runtime.gc() and System.gc()
> ```

None.

> When to use which?

As there is no difference, the choice is purely cosmetic.

Comment: you should at least put some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the javadocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)

"The call System.exit(n) is effectively equivalent to the call: Runtime.getRuntime().exit(n)"

Answer (score 0):

None, they are the same.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: why not? was true then and still is now.

but sure, here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: yeah, but surely there is no good reason to link to outdated docs rather than current ones in such a case.